# Lie groups associated to local Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Lie's Third Theorem states that any real (finite-dimensional) Lie algebra has associated a Lie group. Moreover, this Lie group is a matrix group.

I'm interested to Lie algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ and finite exitensions of $\Bbb Q_p$. Does there exist an analogue of Lie's Third Theorem to such algebras? If so, do you have any reference which I can check?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to have a positive answer, see proposition 17.3 in Schneider's book _$p$-adic Lie Groups_.